# React native using tab navigator and drawer navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I'm totally new to React-native and am currently trying to set up the navigation for my application.

I have a stack navigation that is leading me from the login to the tab navigator. The tab navigator has 4 tabs (HomeRoutes, ProductCatalogueRoutes, MyCustomerRoutes and DrawerRoutes). The last one should open a drawer navigator when clicked on. However, when I click on the 4th tab, the first screen of the drawer navigation appears put I am not able to open the drawer navigation.

I feel like I missed something basic but even after reading through several other questions, I don't get it. Let me know if you need any further information.

Note: Alternatively, it would also be fine for me to have the drawer navigation on the left header position of the tab navigator.

Note 2: I have also changed DrawerNavigation to createDrawerNavigation, etc.

Thanks for your help!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';


import {DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import MyCustomers from "./mycustomers";
import ProductCatalogue from "./productcatalogue";

import Login from "./login";
import Home from "./home";

import Plain from "./plain";


const ProductCatalogueRoutes = StackNavigator({
    ProductCatalogue: { screen: ProductCatalogue },
})

const MyCustomerRoutes = StackNavigator({
    MyCustomers: { screen: MyCustomers },
})

const DrawerRoutes = DrawerNavigator({
    Plain: { screen: Plain},
    MyCustomers: {screen: MyCustomerRoutes},
    ProductCatalogue: {screen:ProductCatalogueRoutes},  
})

const HomeRoutes = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Home },
    // DrawerRoutes: { screen: DrawerRoutes}, //if the drawer menu is part of the header
})

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeRoutes },
    MyCustomers: {screen: MyCustomerRoutes},
    ProductCatalogue: {screen: ProductCatalogueRoutes},
    Menu: {screen: DrawerRoutes}
    },
    {order: [ 'Home', 'ProductCatalogue', 'MyCustomers' , 'Menu'],
     animationEnabled:true,
    }
);


export const Stack = StackNavigator({
        Login: {screen: Login},
        TabNavigation: {screen: Tabs}
    },
    {initialRouteName: 'Login',
        header: null,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
            header: null,
        },
    });


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    title: {
        color: '#ff5d00',
        fontSize: 15,
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginTop: 2,
        opacity: 0.9,
    }
});
```